# Rails 5.0 Comments not showing Event show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building an events site using rails and when I type a comment and hit 'create' the comment doesn't show. This used to work but for some reason now its not. Here's my code -

**Comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController    
  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @comment = @event.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end   
end
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
  <div class="comment clearfix">
    <div class="comment_content">
      <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
      <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    </div>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.event, comment],                     method: :delete, class: "button", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @event.comments.build]) do |f| %>              
  <%= f.label :comment %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm sure its something really obvious but for the life of me I can't spot it.

Comment: It doesn't show? Meaning it is saved and doesn't show or never saved at all?

Comment: It's not showing at all. Or saving.

Comment: Try `@event.comments.create!` and see if you get any exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, now I get a validation failed error - user must exist?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it relates to the upgrade to Rails 5.0 which I've just gone through and, specifically, associations. I had to change my comments associations to `belongs_to :user, optional: true`and away from required: true . The link to where I found the answer is here - https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/issues/215